# Spark With AWS S3 running with docker - Certificate does not match any of the subject alternative names

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

Running into a **weird certificate issue** that I've been debugging for days and took multiple stabs at this.

My application simply uploads a directory to an S3 bucket then pulls down that directory from that same S3 bucket into a spark dataframe.

I'm **only using apache spark, hadoop-aws, aws-java-sdk-bundle**

`Spark version 3.1.1, Scala version 2.12, hadoop version 3.2.0, and aws java sdk version 1.11.901`

- verified AWS secret key and access key are 100% correct
- Running application locally without docker works without any issues

When I try running my application with docker I'm able to upload the directory, but when I try to make an attempt to login and read the directory I run this stacktrace of exceptions (probably just a propagation from the first exception that occurs)

> **Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on s3a://bucket-name/directory: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Certificate for <bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]: Unable to execute HTTP request: Certificate for <bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]**

> **Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Certificate for <bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]**

> **Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]**
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
> at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy60.connect(Unknown Source)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
> at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
> at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1333)
> at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)

I find it odd because my colleague is also using the same credentials as me but he does not run into this issue at all?

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

- Could it be something with the bucket policy or something?

Comment: something is returning an invalid certificate for whatever bucket.s3.amazonaws.com is resolving to. try to debug via browser/curl before going near the aws sdk

Comment: Do you have a "." - dot in the bucket name?

Comment: @dovka Yes, I have also tried with a different bucket name such as ```name1-name2```.

Comment: there seems to be multiple scenarios with this error, for us removing the dots from the bucket name did the trick, but other people report error persisting even in this case. Please see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-18159 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-38330 for recommendations on fixing the drivers

Comment: JIC, leaving this here. After fighting several days with the problem I managed to solve it with `"spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access": "true"` (my bucket has dots as well, and it still works)

Comment: @FelipeGonzalez that's definitively the solution that worked for me. Deserves an answer!

Answer (score 4):

## How to read AWS S3 with Docker, Spark, Python

---

### Docker image:

- [jupyter/pyspark-notebook:spark-3.3.0](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/jupyter/pyspark-notebook/spark-3.3.0/images/sha256-a31d3524bf61ba420b3330432a742e67ce92c7ace9b0d22f0c1b3826e1b0f475?context=explore)

> - `spark_version=3.3.0`
> - `hadoop_version=3`
> - `python_version=3.10.6`

### Pyspark code:

```py
HADOOP_VERSION = '3.3.1'

packages = [
    f'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:{HADOOP_VERSION}',
    'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre',
    'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.14', 
    'com.google.inject:guice:4.2.2', 
    'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:4.2.2'
]

conf = SparkConf().setAll([
    ('spark.jars.packages', ','.join(packages)),
    ('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider'),
    ('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', credentials['AccessKeyId']),
    ('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', credentials['SecretAccessKey']),
    ('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token', credentials['SessionToken']),
    ('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access', True)
])

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

---

Thanks @FelipeGonzalez for the `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access` tip.

Comment: spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access tip was a life saver.
I was a struggling with  the issue for almost 2 days.

thanks  ciurlaro and @FelipeGonzalez